# Messages going to dead letter rather than active queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureservicebus

I have configured service bus and I am sending messages to a topic in it.
I am observing a strange behavior that my messages are going to dead letter queue and not the active queue.

I have checked the properties for my topic like the auto delete on idle, default time to live but not able to figure out the reason.

I tried turning off my listener on this topic hoping some code failure causing the messages to go to dead letter. But still not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Check exceptions log

Comment: Please check the message’s custom properties. You should see the reason for message being deadlettered.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect queue's `MaxDeliverCount`. If dead-lettered messages exceed that value, it's an indication your code was failing to process the messages and they were dead-lettered for that reason. The reason is stated in the `DeadLetterReason` header. If that's the case, as suggested in the comments, log in your code the reason of failure to understand what's happening.

Additional angle to check if your message is getting aborted. This could happen when you use some library or abstraction on top of Azure Service Bus client. If it is, it will eventually get dead-lettered as well. Just like in the first scenario, you'll need some logs to understand why this is happening.